# Is it true that $\frac{1}{meas(\Omega) }\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\in conv [\nabla u(\Omega)]$?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

> Suppose $u\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) $. Then is it true that $\frac{1}{meas(\Omega) }\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\in conv [\nabla u(\Omega)]\ \  ? $
>
> Here $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, bounded.
>
> $\nabla u$ denotes the gradient of $u$. And $conv A$ means convex hull of a set $A$. Here $meas(\Omega) $ is Lebesgue measure of $\Omega$.
>
> A function $u\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) $ means that $u\in L^{\infty}(\Omega) $ and first order weak derivatives of $u$ are also in $L^{\infty}(\Omega) $.

This is a part of a theorem,  named Pyramidal construction , in Differential Inclusions . It has been used to prove the theorem so the above statement is true.  But I can't prove it.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: The result clearly holds true if $\nabla u$ is a step function (i.e. it assumes only a finite number of values). Have you tried to reduce the problem to this case by an approximation argument?

Comment: @Bob yeah it's true for step functions and set of step functions are dense in $L^{\infty}(\Omega) $. But using this how can we conclude,  please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true more generally: for any integrable vector-valued function $g:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^m$ the mean value of $g$ is contained in the convex hull of its [*essential range*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_range).

First, recall that the *closed* convex hull of a set is the intersection of all closed half-spaces containing that set. A closed half-space is described as $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^m : \langle x, a\rangle \ge b\}$ for some  $a\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$. If the range of $g$ is contained in this half-space, then
$$
\left< \frac{1}{\operatorname{meas}(\Omega)} \int_\Omega g, a \right>
=\frac{1}{\operatorname{meas}(\Omega)} \int_\Omega \left< g, a \right>
\ge  \frac{1}{\operatorname{meas}(\Omega)} \int_\Omega b = b
\tag1$$
hence the mean of $g$ is also in the same half-space.

Second, we can remove *closed* by observing that, unless the essential range of $g$ consists of one point, the  mean of $g$ is contained in its relative interior (the interior with respect to the affine span). To this end, replace $V$ by the affine span of the essential range of $g$; this ensures the convex hull has nonempty interior. If the mean of $g$ lies on the boundary of the closed convex hull of the essential range, then there exists a supporting hyperplane at that point, which means having $a, b$ as above such that equality holds in (1). But then $\langle g, a\rangle =b$ a.e., which means the convex hull has empty interior, a contradiction.